# Unable to use webpack dynamic import because of static publicPath

Tags: dynamic, webpack, import

I love the ability to dynamically import a chunk using the `import` command in webpack 3. Unfortunately it seems as if it can only be used if the resources are in a rather static directory configuration on the server.

In my environment the html pages generated dynamically in the backend (let's say `http:/localhost/app`). All other resources (js, css, images, etc.) are in a different directory (let's say `http:/localhost/res`) but additionally `res` is not static but can rather change dynamically in the backend.

As long as I do not use any dynamic imports everything works as expected but when trying to dynamically load any chunks this fails because webpack by default expects the chunks to be in `http:/localhost/app` and I cannot use `publicPath` because the url where the resources are is dynamic.

Is there any way to (runtime) configure webpack into loading the resources relative to the path where the current resource is located.
If for example the chunk `page1.js` located in `http:/localhost/resA` dynamically loads the chunk `sub1.js` he should look for it in `http:/localhost/resA` instead of `http:/localhost/app`.

**generated html will be available at `http:/localhost/app/page1`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="http:/localhost/resA/page1.bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**file `src/page1.js` will be available as `http:/localhost/resA/page1.bundle.js`:**

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "sub1" */ './sub1').then(({MyClass}) => {/*...*/});
```

**file `src/sub1` will be available as `http:/localhost/resA/sub1.bundle.js`:**

```
export class MyClass {};
```

**file `webpack.config.js':**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

function config(env) {
    return {
        entry: {
            index: ['./src/page1.js']
        },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].bundle.js',
            chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            publicPath: './'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/i,
                    include: /src/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader'
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        devtool: 'source-map'
    };
}

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to use `__webpack_public_path__` as described in https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path.

Comment: And why is that short reference to the public documentation the solution to your problem? Your problem statement was very detailed, and the solution is not.

Comment: Is it possible to override the public path for assets specified in css during the runtime? If not how does one generally do it?